# Текст после радио-кнопки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть радио-кнопки вида:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="1"> А) Белый<br>
```

Я получаю доступ к группе через

```
var group = document.getElementsByName('question_1');
```

а далее мне нужно взять текст после инпута.
Беру любую кнопку через group[0], а как взять текст после нее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш текст можно огорнуть в теги (либо <label>,<span> и.т.д.) и обращатся уже к ним.
Обратится к нему можно [nextSibling](http://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom#parentnode-previoussibling-%D0%B8-nextsibling)

Comment: @zloctb, у меня получилось даже без обертки в теги. Но спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Если огорнуть текст в <label> это дает возможность выбирать флажок по клику на текст

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда. Решение находишь сразу как задашь вопрос.
Может кому понадобится. Выдрал фаербагом:

```
group[0].nextSibling.wholeText;
```